# Organizando campos de formulario

Tags: html

Sou novo em programaçao, queria saber como faço para organizar os campos do meu seguinte formulario de modo que fiquem alinhados tanto o label quanto os inputs, e que campos de interesse iguais, como por exemplo (nome e sobrenome), (rua, numero, cidade e estado) fiquem lado a lado.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.form {
  display: flex;
  width: 550px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=date],
input[type=email], input[type=password], select {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}



input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #FF6347;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=reset]:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/formstyle-user.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Cadastrar Usuario</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<form class="form" method="post" action="#">
 <div class="area">
  <fieldset id="usuario">
   <legend>Dados Pessoais</legend>
    <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
     <input type="text" name=" nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" required="">

   <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" required>

    <label for="cpf">CPF: </label>
     <input type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="000.000.000-00" required>

    <label for="dtnasc">Data Nasc: </label>
     <input type="date" name="dtnasc" id="dtnasc" required>

   <fieldset id="sexo">
     <legend>Sexo: </legend>
     <label for="masc">Masculino<input type="radio" name="sexo" id="masc" checked required></label>
     <label for="fem">Feminino<input type="radio" name="sexo" id="fem" required></label>
   </fieldset>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="endereco">
   <legend>Endereço</legend>

    <label for="rua">Logradouro: </label> <input type="text" name="rua" id="rua" placeholder="João Alvez" required>

    <label for="numero">Número: </label><input type="number" name="numero" id="numero" required>

    <label for="bairro">Bairro: </label><input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" >

    <label for="estados">Estado: </label>
     <select id="estados" required>
      <option value=""></option>
     </select>

    <label for="cidades">Cidade: </label>
     <select id="cidades" required>
      <option value=""></option>
     </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="login">
   <legend>Dados para Login</legend>

    <label for="email">E-mail: </label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="senha">Senha: </label><input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" required>

    <label for="confirma_senha">Confirmar Senha: </label> <input type="password" name="confirma_senha" id="confirma_senha" required>
    

    <label for="nivel">Nível de acesso: </label>
     <select name="nivel" id="nivel" required>
      <option value="">---</option>
      <option value="#">1-Administrador</option>
      <option value="#">2-Técnico</option>
      <option value="#">3-Comum</option>
     </select>

    <label for="cel">Cel: <input type="text" name="cel" id="cel" required></label>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
  <input type="reset" name="Limpar" value="Limpar">
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas de fazer isso seria colocar cada campo em uma div. Segue um exemplo:

```
<div class="campo">
<label for="rua">Logradouro: </label> <input type="text" name="rua" id="rua" placeholder="João Alvez" required>
</div>
```

Depois, aplicar um estilo para esta classe, para fazer o alinhamento dos campos lado a lado.

Fiz um ajuste no seu formulário, o HTML ficou da seguinte forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/formstyle-user.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Cadastrar Usuario</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 @charset "UTF-8";


.campo {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

.campo input {
  margin: 10px 1%;
  padding: 8px 1%;
  width: 90%;
}

.campo select {
  margin: 10px 1%;
  padding: 8px 1%;
  width: 94%;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  width: 550px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=date],
input[type=email], input[type=password], select {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}



input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #FF6347;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=reset]:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<form class="form" method="post" action="#">
 <div class="area">
  <fieldset id="usuario">
   <legend>Dados Pessoais</legend>
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
     <input type="text" name=" nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" required="">
    </div> 

   <div class="campo">
   <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" required>
   </div>
   
   <div class="campo">
    <label for="cpf">CPF: </label>
     <input type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="000.000.000-00" required>
   </div>
   
   <div class="campo">
    <label for="dtnasc">Data Nasc: </label>
     <input type="date" name="dtnasc" id="dtnasc" required>
   </div>
   <fieldset id="sexo">
     <legend>Sexo: </legend>
     <label for="masc">Masculino<input type="radio" name="sexo" id="masc" checked required></label>
     <label for="fem">Feminino<input type="radio" name="sexo" id="fem" required></label>
   </fieldset>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="endereco">
   <legend>Endereço</legend>
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="rua">Logradouro: </label> <input type="text" name="rua" id="rua" placeholder="João Alvez" required>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
    <label for="numero">Número: </label><input type="number" name="numero" id="numero" required>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
    <label for="bairro">Bairro: </label><input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" >
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="estados">Estado: </label>
     <select id="estados" required>
      <option value=""></option>
     </select>
    </div> 

    <div class="campo">
    <label for="cidades">Cidade: </label>
     <select id="cidades" required>
      <option value=""></option>
     </select>
    </div> 
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="login">
   <legend>Dados para Login</legend>
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="email">E-mail: </label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="senha">Senha: </label><input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" required>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
    <label for="confirma_senha">Confirmar Senha: </label> <input type="password" name="confirma_senha" id="confirma_senha" required>
    </div> 

    <div class="campo">
    <label for="nivel">Nível de acesso: </label>
     <select name="nivel" id="nivel" required>
      <option value="">---</option>
      <option value="#">1-Administrador</option>
      <option value="#">2-Técnico</option>
      <option value="#">3-Comum</option>
     </select>

    </div>

    <div class="campo"> 
    <label for="cel">Cel: <input type="text" name="cel" id="cel" required></label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
  <input type="reset" name="Limpar" value="Limpar">
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado amigo